# Liquibase scripts not getting executed when app is packaged

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I’m facing a strange issue with Liquibase (I am using 3.4.2) :

- When I start the application from my IDE, new scripts get deployed with no issue.
- When I package my application (as a jar) and deploy it in my CI pipeline, scripts don’t get executed and I get below error :

> INFO 8 --- [ main] liquibase : Successfully acquired change log lock
>   WARN 8 --- [ main] liquibase : included file classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml/ is not a recognized file type

I’m using includeAll mode:

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: changes
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
```

Also, in case it makes a difference, I have several modules in my application (a Spring Boot app) :

- My main application is moduleA : this is the jar I build and run
- moduleA has a dependency on moduleB, in which the Liquibase scripts are

problem seems to be similar to the one described here : http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/includeall-not-working-for-multimodule-project-with-spring , but no solution is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying various things, like including files one by one, or upgrade Liquibase version, it looks like the simplest way to get this to work is to tweak spring-boot-maven-plugin config for moduleA by unpacking files : this way, Liquibase is able to find the files it’s looking for.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <requiresUnpack>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
                        <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </requiresUnpack>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```